# Is there a proof that the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ that starts with $\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{(y - x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As in title: Is there a proof that the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ that starts with / uses $\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{(y - x)}$, i.e. not the other one $\frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}h$?

Comment: Huh? What’s the difference? You can always write $y$ for $x+h$ and vice versa, right?

Comment: Just pick any proof that uses $h$ and substitute $y-x$ for $h$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Be sure you can justify the following (trigonometric identities, continuity, basic limits...)

$$\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}=2\frac{\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2}{x-y}=$$

$$=\cos\frac{x+y}2\cdot\frac{\sin\frac{x-y}2}{\frac{x-y}2}\xrightarrow[x\to y]{}\cos\frac{2y}2\cdot1=\cos y$$